# Can anyone please Explain the recursion logic of this program?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, output

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N>  
{
class P 
{

    public:
    static void print() 
    {
         P<N-1>::print();
         std::cout << N << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
class P<1> {
public:
    static void print() 
    {
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    const int N = 10;
    P<N>::print();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the below code is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

the program first counts down from 10 to 1 and then once N value becomes 1
P<1>::print is called. I don't understand how after this call, N value increases
by 1 till N=10.can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Can you identify the **first thing** that `P<10>::print()` will do?

Comment: If you simplified this problem to instead call `P<2>::print()`, you may find it easy to step through every single line of code that results in `1 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you understand this program?

```
void p10_print() {p9_print(); std::cout << 10 << std::endl;}
void p9_print() {p8_print(); std::cout << 9 << std::endl;}
void p8_print() {p7_print(); std::cout << 8 << std::endl;}
void p7_print() {p6_print(); std::cout << 7 << std::endl;}
void p6_print() {p5_print(); std::cout << 6 << std::endl;}
void p5_print() {p4_print(); std::cout << 5 << std::endl;}
void p4_print() {p3_print(); std::cout << 4 << std::endl;}
void p3_print() {p2_print(); std::cout << 3 << std::endl;}
void p2_print() {p1_print(); std::cout << 2 << std::endl;}
void p1_print() {std::cout << 1 << std::endl;}
int main() {
    p10_print();
    return 0;
}
```

It's the same program. The templates cause the compiler to create all these functions for you.

In case you still can't understand it: p2_print() doesn't print a 2 until *after* p1_print() returns. p2_print() calls p1_print() which prints 1, then it prints 2. p3_print() calls p2_print() which prints 1 2, then it prints 3. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at 3 as a smaller example:

```
P<3>::print calls P<2>::print
.    P<2>::print calls P<1>::print
.    .    P<1>::print prints 1
.    .    Then returns to P<2>::print
.    Then prints 2
.    Then returns to P<3>::print
Then prints 3
Then returns to main
```

Because the print is placed after the recursive call, the prints happen on the way up the stack while returning from the functions rather than down the stack while calling into functions. Thus, the inner one prints first and the outer one last. If you swap the two statements, the print order is reversed.

`N` goes up because each `P<N>::print` is *returning* to `P<N+1>::print`. On the way in, `N` goes down instead.